# Angularjs Ajax get sending headers

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, http

I'm new to angularjs, and im using a service for my http requests.
one of the rest api's i need to send  key value pairs in the header.
username: foo
password: bar

how do i do it using the http request format i have in my service. (i'm aware i need to pass an argument in the function i don't how to go about it and what object format)

.service('UserService', ['$http', '$rootScope', function ($http, $rootScope) {

```
    this.CheckIfUserExists = function () {
        return $http.get($rootScope.endPoint + '/user/email_token');
    };
```

}

...

//in the controller

```
UserService.CheckIfUserExist()
      .success(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        //handler
          }).
         error(function(error) {
        //handler

          });
```

Answer (score 0):

Example from the [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)
you need know what kind of auth. you can use post for example.

.service('UserService', ['$http', '$rootScope', function ($http, $rootScope) {
    var req = {
     method: 'POST',
     url: 'http://example.com',
     headers: {
       'Content-Type': undefined
     },
     data: { test: 'test' }
    }

```
$http(req).success(function(){...}).error(function(){...});
```

In your case:

```
.service('UserService', ['$http', '$rootScope', function ($http, $rootScope) {   
    this.CheckIfUserExists = function () {
        var req = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://example.com'
            data: { 'username': 'foo', 'password': 'bar' }
        };
        return $http(req);
    } 
}
```

Comment: I suppose like in my update, but it is impossible to know without the server specs.